# Bootstrap hover popover scrolls page to top

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive

I'm having an issue with bootstrap popovers.  When you mouseover the element, it scrolls you to the top of the page. this is what I have so far.   I tried adding a preventDefault call to avoid the scroll and I'm not really sure what else to try.  Any help is greatly appreciated :)

```
.directive( 'popover', ['$compile', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<a href="#" bs-popover="popover" html="true" trigger="hover" student-name ng-click="popupStudentInfo(student.id);" class="student-name">{{student.full_name}}</a>',
        replace: true,
        link: function( scope, elem, attrs ) {
            $(elem).on('mouseover', function(e) {e.preventDefault(); return true;});

            scope.$watch('student', function() {
                    $(elem).on('mouseover', function(e) {e.preventDefault(); return true;});
                    var math_color = '';
                    if (scope.student.math_pass_rate > 80) {
                        math_color = 'green';
                    } else if (scope.student.math_pass_rate >= 51) {
                        math_color = 'orange';
                    } else {
                        math_color = 'red';
                    }
                    var lit_color = '';
                    if (scope.student.literacy_pass_rate > 80) {
                        lit_color = 'green';
                    } else if (scope.student.literacy_pass_rate >= 51) {
                        lit_color = 'orange';
                    } else {
                        lit_color = 'red';
                    }
                    scope.popover = {
                    "title": "<i class='beta icon-book left'></i><div>" +
                    "Level " + scope.student.v1_student.math_level + "<br>" +
                    "<span class='" + math_color + "'>" + Math.round(scope.student.math_pass_rate) + " % Pass Rate" + "</span><br>" +
                    scope.student.math_completed + " Passed / " + (scope.student.math_attempted + scope.student.math_completed) + " Attempted</div>" +
                    "<i class='beta icon-calculate left'></i><div> Level " + scope.student.v1_student.literacy_level + "<br><span class='" + lit_color + "'>" + Math.round(scope.student.literacy_pass_rate) + " % Pass Rate</span><br>" +
                    scope.student.literacy_completed + " Passed / " + (scope.student.literacy_attempted + scope.student.literacy_completed) + " Attempted</div>"


                    ,
                     "content": "<span></span>",
                     "html": true
                 };
             }, true)
        }
    }
}])
```

Comment: Have you looked at this before? http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: yes I have, i haven't found anything that works on for me on there :(

Comment: Are you able to create a fiddle that produces the problem?

Comment: I ended up working with the creator of the plugin to fix the issue, there was a problem in the lib.